# SPO How to Add a Web Part Zone to the Search Center Main Page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, page-layout

The boss is asking for a (rotating) list of search tips on the main page for our new Sharepont Online Search Center.

It appears that there is no easy way to do this...

What do I need to do?

Comment: Please elaborate Barry. Is this the scenario that you simply wish to add a List of "Formatted Text" on the Main page of your Search center?

Comment: Thx @mohd, i am being asked to add some search tips in a list on the right side of the main Search Center page. Seems like it should be easily done. When I tried modifying the Page Layout, the Add Zone menu item was disabled... How can I make this happen?

Comment: You should change the title of this Question. You are not asking about a new web part zone, you are asking about content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @Barry this can be easily done. You may consider trying options from the top ribbon(after clicking **Edit page** from the gear. Or the other option is to use HTML/CSS, If you feel like adding special formatting to the List 'Text'.

1.) Just click on Edit-Page from the gear.

2.) Insert the webpart '**Script Editor**' from the '**Media and Content**' section.

3.) Check reference for adding CSS/HTML https://jsfiddle.net/wzo9wahm/, I had added it in my sharepoint page.

4.) If you wish to move the 'Text' to the right side of the page, simply add some css for Margin-Left to the class.

If this answer helped, please up-vote it and mark it up. Else let me know if you need more help.